# android nfc read and write at the same time/one contact

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to read data from an NFC tag and then save the data back to the NFC tag.
Is it necessary to connect the NFC tag to the smartphone for each access (read / write) and then remove it again, or is it possible to leave the NFC tag on the mobile phone while the data is being read out and then stored again on it.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Maximillian Do you have any code that you are having a problem with, or are you just trying to figure out if it is possible? Adding the code you have tried so far will greatly increase the possibility that you'll find an answer.

Comment: Definitely possible, but please explain your exact use case (which data is read/write, what's the exact tag technology you use, what environment are you talking about) ... Probably it is even doable with MIT AppInventor ...

Comment: @Mximillian, I didn't read your question thorough, my apologies, you mentioned tags, and I just saw NFC communications and answered quickly. Please see my update, you can definitely do this.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but you will probably need to do it with the `NfcA` class and not with the convenient helpers.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
Since I was down voted, I realized I did not read your question fully. You are dealing with tags and not Beam NFC P2P, so allow me to update my answer to include Tag back and forths.

First you tap and get your tag from your manifest filtered tag types.
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);

Then you can then connect() and 
writeNdefMessage(…)

There is no need to pull away and tap again.

Also here are some helpful tools if you don't want to write the bloat. https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android

Old Answer: (leaving in case it helps someone in the P2P NFC space)
This was based on P2P beam NFC technology if you are communicating with an NFC device like Google Pay for example where you can do many back and forth as long as you are near. Take Google Payment NFC for example, it reads the info from your device, then does a handshake back and forth via NFC and then performs the transaction. I actually wrote a software that did this exact thing for Gift Card processing and secure encryption handshake back and forth.

It requires a little extra work in your coding, but you can definitely do it.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

see this topic for details. It is not quite the same as a quick read or write, but you can definitely go back and forth no problem.